# Jquery Toggleclass not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggleclass

I have this code but i don't know why not work toggleclass ???

```
$('.nopadding').click(function() {

    var icon = $(this).children().children().children().eq(0);
    var servicebox = $(this).children();

    $('.nopadding .show-for-small-only').removeClass('rotate');
    $('.nopadding .servicebox').removeClass('showservice');
    icon.toggleClass('rotate');
    servicebox.toggleClass('showservice');  
    return false;

});
```

here example works only on mobile size https://jsfiddle.net/aovza3v7/1/

Comment: Where is toggleClass() in your code?  It's unclear what your problem is.

Comment: Post your HTML code as well. Maybe even make a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) demonstrating the problem.

Comment: 1: I don't see any use of toggleClass(). 2: Icon selector is difficult to read, try `var icon = $(this).find('.element');` 3: When using toggleClass(), define 'not work' - do you get a javascript error, or does it do nothing?